# get item Listview

Tags: android, listview

I'm having a problem of getting item that are not visible in ListView. What I want is once the user has finished putting data in all EditText in a listview, I get all those values using a loop. But the issue is once the user has finished, with the loop I only get values visible on the screen and the rest the view returns null. any help please here is my code below. `

```
Log.e("size of:"," size listStudent(listview)--"+number);
for (int i=0;i<number;i++) {
      View view = listStudent.getChildAt(i);
      if(view !=null){
           Log.e("size of:","counter"+i);
           studentIdTxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.student_id_ls);
           obtainedTxt = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.obtained);
           maxTxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.max);
           student = studentIdTxt.getText().toString().trim();
           obtained_value = obtainedTxt.getText().toString().trim();
           max_value = maxTxt.getText().toString().trim();
           //updating the new mark list array
           HashMap<String,String>studentMark=new HashMap<String,String>();
           studentMark.put(TAG_STUDENT_ID,student);
           studentMark.put(TAG_MARKS_OBTAINED,obtained_value);
           studentMark.put(TAG_MARKS_MAX, max_value);
           studentMarksList.add(studentMark);
      }
 }
 //start of calling the JSON transmitter
 JSONTransmitter transmitter=new JSONTransmitter();
 //set the url
 String url=domain+"/app/caller.php";
 //transform studentMarksList to json
 String studentList=gson.toJson(studentMarksList);
 transmitter.setUrl(url);
```

Everything works fine, it's only that I can't get those item visible when you scroll. "number" is equal to 29 but the counter only iterates up to 4. Any help please!

Answer (score 0):

```
listStudent.getChildAt(i);
```

A child view can only be retrieved from listview if it is visible on the screen.
Use a `setOnFocusChangeListener` for each `EditText` in the adapter (I assume you're using a custom adapter). When the user is done putting data, retrieve the text and update the list accordingly.

[This](https://dzone.com/articles/list-editable-textboxes) is a tutorial if you need one.

Comment: yes that I know, that's why I'm asking for any other possible way to do the job. Thanks!